# Homepage was doubled and cannot be adjusted in Elements

Tags: homepage

Could anyone help us with a problem with WordPress website?
We met with a problem that the homepage was doubled and we couldn't adjust it in Elements. We can create new items in Elements and it works well, but once we return to the website it showed a doubled item page.
Is there any other ways to adjust the webpage or check the html of the website?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "elements"? Sounds like you're using 3rd party code such as Elementor/VC/.. Have you tried contacting the authors directly with this issue?

Comment: Do you mean Elementor? It's not clear what you mean by Elements, if it's a theme, a feature, a plugin, or a service, or just what your developer has named your site